# Power Automate - Update last row in an Excel table

Tags: excel, power-automate

I currently use an Excel spreadsheet to store all users 4 digit printer code. This 4 digit code is incremental so when a new user joins our team, their code will be 1 digit higher than the previous user who joined, e.g. previous user code 1122, new user code 1123.

[printer codes sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10QOb.png)

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Submit a form via MS forms with the basic details of the new user. The flow then adds the information from the form and adds it to the printer code excel sheet.
2. The flow will grab the printer code of the previous user above and raise the value by 1  and assign it to the new user added.

For the most part this process is working as intended. Where is it failing is the flow isn't grabbing the code from the previous user, but the code 250 rows earlier.

Please see my flow below:

[Getting form details and listing rows in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PowxK.png)

I then use 2 compose actions to grab the last row in the table and then update the value by 1:

[grab last row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZvj8.png)
[add + 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOvLl.png)

The information from the form is then added to the spreadsheet table, using output 2 as the content for the Code column.

[Add row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saka0.png)

From what I can gather the problem is my first compose formula, as the incremental compose is adding +1, but not to the row above.

[compose input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrZbh.png)

[compose 2 input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS73a.png)

The code the flow grabbed was 1388 as it will add the code 1389. But the last user added is 1641 so the new user should have a code of 1642.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong and could share it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my post to include the inputs and output of the 2 compose actions. I think the issue is my first compose action isnt grabbing the last row but one 250 rows earlier.

Comment: You could try to adjust the “list rows ..” by sorting descending (order) by the Code column and choosing top count 1 , then you get as output only one row with the max code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to get the row with the highest value in column “Code”:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. This has fixed my flow by adding Code desc to list a row in a table. When submitting the same response it will use the same code number, but when submitting a new response it updates the number to the new correct number.